# How to convert a byte object to a list of tuples in python 3?

Tags: python, list, io, tuples, byte

I have a list of tuples [(x,y,z),...,] and I want to store this list of tuples in a file. For this I chose a .txt file. I write to the file in the mode "wb" and then I close it. Later, I want to open the file in mode "rb" and convert this byte object back to a list of tuples. How would I go about this without regular expression nonsense? Is there a file type that would allow me to store this data and read it easily that I've overlooked?

Comment: Use `pickle`: no text files, no parsing, no regexes, just `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.txt` extension is typically not used for binary data, as you seem to intend.

Since your data structure is not known on a byte level, it's not that simple.
If you do know your data (types and length), you could "encode" it as a binary structure with https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html and write that to a (binary) file.

Otherwise, there are many solutions to the problem of writing (structured) data to and reading data from files (that's why there are soo many file formats):

Standard library:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileformats.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

3rd party:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML

and other modules on https://pypi.python.org/

Related Q&A on Stackoverflow:

- [How to save data with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389738/how-to-save-data-with-python)